# How to solve complex derivatives with multiple terms?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I have several derivatives to find:

> For $g(s)=3s^3-s+4$, $g'(s)=$
>
> For $p(t)=\frac1t+t^2$, $\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dt}=$
>
> For $w(u)=\sqrt u-2u^2-10$, $\frac{\mathrm dw}{\mathrm du}=$

Each has multiple terms, and as a result is difficult to determine how to solve.
I need to find out how to go about solving these, for example I can't use the power rule because these functions have more than just one term.

I am looking for insight on what steps to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

All three problems can be solved by combining three facts:

1. $D_x(f(x)\pm g(x))=D_x(f(x))\pm D_x(g(x))$
2. $D_x(cf(x))=cD_x(f(x))$ for any constant $c$
3. $D_x(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$ for any $n\neq 0$ (including $n=-1$ and $n=\frac12$.)

---

In the first problem, the submitted solution takes −s and replaces it with +s, which certainly isn't the derivative of $-s$ with respect to $s$. In the second solution, it looks like the user doesn't know what the derivative of 1/t is, and in the third solution looks overcomplicated and contains an x for some reason.

Comment: Could you show me a walkthrough on how you complete one of them? I don't have an instructor for this course. It is self teach + exam. Thanks

Comment: @Andrew These hints are already very strong. If you take a look at the example in the other solution, and then tell me how your work is proceeding in the comments here, I'll let you know if you're getting off track.

Comment: For 1/t + t^2 I did this:

1) Flip 1/t to the numerator so term 1 is (-1)1t^0 which equals -1  
2) apply power rule to t^2 -> 2t^1 = 2t  

this should give me 2t - 1 but it isn't working

Comment: Also for sqrt(u) - 2u^2 - 10, i did this:

sqrt(u) is a constant so = 0,
-2u^2 apply the power rule and end up with -4u, -10 is a constant so = 0. But -4u is not working :(

Comment: @Andrew Firstly: flip to $t^{-1}$ is a good idea, but you are making a mistake with the power rule. It says to *subtract* 1 from the power... but you *added*! Secondly: $\sqrt{u}$ is not constant! From he context you see that $u$ is a variable, and $\sqrt{u}$ changes while $u$is changing. Do you know how to express $\sqrt{u}$ as a power of u?

Comment: sqrt(u) = u^(1/2) correct?

Comment: @andrew right. Got corrections to your work now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: @Andrew No problem: hope my comments helped!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** 
 Derivatives are linear, i.e. $$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\Big[f(x)+g(x)\Big]=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)+\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}g(x).$$
As an example: let $h(x)=x^2-x$, we then have: $$h'(x)=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\Big[x^2-x\Big]=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}x^2+\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(-x)=2x-1.$$